# Detect Excel File Format Type via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to import an `xlsx` worksheet into an `xls` workbook and ran into an error regarding the number of rows is greater in the `xlsx` then the `xls`. I'd like to add a check to the beginning of my macro which detects in the open workbook is `xls` and then saves as `xlsx` and re-opens with new format.

I am fairly certain I can do this via checking the "file extension", but I'd feel better utilizing some sort of function built into Excel/VBA which can detect if a file is "Excel 97-2003" style workbook as users can simply change a file extension without changing file type. Is there a way to programmatically check what type of `workbook` is currently open? `ActiveWorkbook`.

I don't have any code to share as all I can find is related to checking if file is open, or checking file extension etc etc. Perhaps my google-fu is off today, but I am not getting anything related in my searches so I have tried nothing.

Comment: e,g,: `If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns.Count = 256 Then`: An `.xls` file has only 256 columns.

Comment: @VBasic2008 thats only a step above checking file extension, I was hoping to find a function built for this exact purpose which "BigBen" has shown in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the [`Workbook.FileFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.fileformat) property:

> Returns the file format and/or type of the workbook. Read-only [XlFileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)

```
If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = xlExcel8 Then
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End If
```